# WPF or Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

So I'm looking at creating a desktop based application that will connect to a SQL Database to pull data. This application will have buttons that will access information off a share drive. The user will also have the ability to submit things to the database as well.

My question is which project type would better serve to create this with a good and sold UI, and make it look nice and function well and solid?

This application will run on Windows 7 with .NET 3.5 (trying to talk them into going to .NET 4.5 hasn't worked.)

Comment: WPF is pretty hard to learn. If you are a beginner, I'l suggest you start with WINFORMS. Though WPF is more modern and flexible.

Comment: I've voted to close this question, because it is "primarily opinion-based". However, in my opinion you should use WPF. The times of WinForms are long gone. Learning WPF will also lead you to other, even more modern technologies like Windows Store Apps.

Comment: I know this is primarily opinion based, but I didn't know anywhere else to ask and get quality answers. Thank you for your thoughts though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF is much more customizable. So it can offer a better look and feel.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2c112462-5162-4f25-8710-496495105e29/data-binding-in-wpf-compare-to-windows-forms?forum=wpf

extract:

> I think the main advantage of WPF over Windows Forms is not data
>   binding, but data templating: the type of the data can determine the
>   UI that is instantiated, and this UI can be defined in a concise,
>   easy, declarative way using XAML.

Answer (score 2):

(I can't comment, otherwise I would)

This is really subjective, WPF and WinForms can both make solid UI's that look nice and perform well.

WPF has advantages of being able to do skinning, and focuses on separating the designer (as a job function) from the programmer. You can hand a UI in WPF to a designer with Blend and get back a functional UI without backend code changes.

This is much more difficult in Winforms. The advantage Winforms currently has is that it can be cross-platform if designed correctly with no changes (using Mono).

What you choose is entirely based on the goals and requirements of the application and environment.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would use WPF as it gives you so much more flexibility regarding design than Win Forms.  It has been in the .NET Framework since .NET 3.0 so it should be ok on 3.5.

WPF will require learning XAML but it is very transferable as you can use it in Silverlight as well as for Windows 8 apps for both mobile and desktop.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I would think either would be fine based on the information.

Although I kind of prefer WPF.

As far as the UI being good and solid and looking nice, that really depend on how its made, but their are some good free libraries you can get for project that might help make that easier

For example: [Fabtab](https://fabtab.codeplex.com/)

I've tried this one and it has some nice functionality